# How to re-position Navigation Bar Buttons in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar

I have implemented the `navigationBarTitle` and I am trying to implement a `navigationBarItem` however the default position looks odd. 
[image]

I want to be able to position the Next button in line with the `navigationBarTitle`. I was able to accomplish something with this code:

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Names"))
.navigationBarItems(trailing:
            Button(action: {
                print("tapped")
            }) {
                Group {
                    Text("Next")
                }.position(x: 0, y: 60).background(Color.purple)

            })
```

However the issue it that the button did not move, so it's not tappable where it displays Next. (I highlighted the position purple to demonstrate.)
[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this in a cleaner fashion? Or other methods or stacks that I could implement while keeping the `navigationBarTitle` Large Tile look in SwiftUI? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the button in a `ZStack` and position the `Button` inside of the `ZStack` like this:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

 struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Names")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Names"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    ZStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                print("tapped")
                            }) {
                                Group {
                                    Text("Next")
                                }.background(Color.purple)
                            }.position(x: 0, y: 60)
                        })
        }
    }
}

let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

I tried it in the above playground example and it worked:

[image]

**Edit:**

This appears to make the button unresponsive unless you touch and drag:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I tried this and it makes my button unresponsive when I click on it. I've tried moving the `.position` modifier to the end of the Group and to the end of the button with no luck. It is responsive when `(x: 0, y: 0)`.

Comment: Hmm this seems to be a bug with SwiftUI. I *am* able to press the button but only if I click from above right of button and drag down. I'm gonna edit my answer with a clip of this odd behavior.

Comment: There is a bug with navigation bar buttons in a large navigation bar title not working after you present a sheet that may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58512956/296708. You *can* press the button but only with a drag gesture.

Comment: Ah that’s interesting , i’m seeing the same behavior when i run it also. thanks for your help!